# Analyzing coredump from java app on android

Tags: android, gdb, dalvik, coredump

I have a core dump from dalvik process (it was com.android.browser).
I definitely know, that process was terminated somewhere in JNI module.

Also, I have all debug symbols for that device. But I can't invoke gdb for this coredump.
I'm trying like this:

```
arm-eabi-gdb ../symbols/system/bin/dalvikvm android.browser_5879_1354575922.core
```

but gdb says:

```
warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
.....
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers
and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.
Core was generated by `com.android.browser'          
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
```

so `(gdb) info sharedlibrary` displays nothing:

```
No shared libraries loaded at this time.
```

How to properly load coredump for dalvikvm process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, answer was to provide app_process as image name:

arm-eabi-gdb symbols/system/bin/**app_process** android.browser_5879_1354575922.core

Comment: Dalvik is built into a shared library (libdvm.so), and started from "inside" other processes.  "dalvikvm" is a command-line wrapper around libdvm.so.  As you discovered, app_process is effectively the binary for all apps; it starts Dalvik after doing some app framework initialization.